# How to embed a map using the inset_element() function from the patchwork package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm trying to make a small map embedded on a large map using the inset_element() function from the patchwork package.

I get this error when trying to inset a map:

```
Error in seq.default(design$t[i], design$b[i]) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
```

here is an example:

```
library(patchwork)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale='medium',returnclass = 'sf')
p1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data= world)

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(x= Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length))

# 2 maps = fail
p1 + inset_element(p1, left =0.75, right =0.95, bottom = 0.75, top =0.95)

# 1 map as "main" = success
p1 + inset_element(p2, left =0.75, right =0.95, bottom = 0.75, top =0.95)


# 1 map as "inset" = fail
p2 + inset_element(p1, left =0.75, right =0.95, bottom = 0.75, top =0.95)

packageVersion("patchwork")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inset_element` seems to be a new feature in patchwork, and I think you have discovered a bug which has also [affected other users](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/214). The error is thrown in [this line](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/blob/579d7f131c17f3360ee09e40ea408f62f06866e9/R/plot_patchwork.R#L711) in `set_panel_dimensions`, which is only called when you try to print (rather than create) this patchwork object:

```r
fail <- p2 + inset_element(p1, left =0.75, right =0.95, bottom = 0.75, top =0.95)

fail
#> Error in seq.default(design$t[i], design$b[i]) : 
#>   'from' must be a finite number
```

However, we can work round this error for now by setting the layout height and width for the `patches` object to 1:

```r
fail$patches$layout$widths  <- 1
fail$patches$layout$heights <- 1

fail
```

[image]

I have referenced this answer in the patchwork github issues thread mentioned above.